# unrar: An error occurred while accessing the archive

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu

I can't seem to unrar files. When I right-click and hit "extract here" it throws up an error message: "An error occurred while accessing the archive". I have unrar installed. I also tried 7-zip rar. No luck. Can someone help me?

Comment: Would the archive happen to be password protected?

Answer (score 8):

1. Open a terminal and do:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install unrar
   ```
2. Now you can actually extract it with:

   ```
   unrar x -r /path/to/rarfile.rar
   ```

Comment: I'm still having issues. The first rar I tried to unrar seemed to extract OK but then I didn't see any files extracted into the folder. The second one I tried to unrar threw up more error messages. Here's a pastebin of my terminal. https://pastebin.com/z5dVdGcy

Comment: @XanthReborn: Where did you look for the files listed in the output of `unrar`?

Comment: My case was because the split archive files where password protected but Ubuntu default unarchiver did not asked for password and failed to extract the files.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should install the right command:

```
apt-get install unrar
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install unrar
```

In case you can't do that, download directly the packet from this [link](http://www.rarlab.com/download.htm)

Than untar the package with:

```
tar -xvfz packagename
```

So now, the 2 commands rar and unrar can found inside the sub-directory rar so:

```
cd rar  #with this command you move inside the directory
./unrar  #with this command you launch the unrar command
```

Now you have to copy the 2 commands inside /usr/local/bin so:

```
cp rar unrar /usr/local/bin
```

After do that you will be able to use cmd in these ways.

Unrar file inside the current directory:

```
unrar e file.rar
```

List what is inside the rar:

```
unrar l file.rar
```

You can find all this infomation on this [guide](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/open-rar-file-or-extract-rar-files-under-linux-or-unix/).

Comment: I followed the instructions on there and it worked! Thank you!

Comment: I used: 'unrar e UBW.rar' and it worked